# I have imported CSV files as new layers, saved them as shapefiles, but the points are not rendering onscreen: they are at the top of the stack

Tags: qgis, csv, rendering

M1 Mac, OS Monterey 12.2.1; QGIS v 3.16. If I select one of these layers and choose 'zoom to layer', it zooms to where the points should be but they are not visible, so clearly, their positions are correct they just are not displaying: [image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the first few lines of the .csv file.

Comment: Ok, have done that.

Comment: OK.  Problem solved, it was a CRS mismatch between the layers and the Project CRS.  Thanks for replies.